# App working on USB debug phone ,but not on other?

Tags: development-environment, environment

I made an app with recycler view configuration, it's working fine in my USB debug phone but when I am installing it on other phone it then crashes.

Comment: Then you should debug on that other phone from Android Studio to see where the app is dying.  It could be an Android version issue, or it could be something else.

Comment: Your other phone's `api-version` should be > `minSdk` mentioned in the `gradle.config`